# ASP.NET Core 2.0 resource access_token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, powerbi, asp.net-core-2.0

How do I acquire a *OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken* for a given resource (ex/ Power BI)?

I created a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC project in VS2017 that uses AAD for authentication. Given an authenticated user, I need to get a resource **access_token** so that I can then make web api calls to said resource.

For my specific case, I'm trying to access Power BI content but this also applies to other resources such as graphQL.

So far I've managed to get an idtoken which unfortunately doesn't seem to authenticate against the resource. My attempts to fetch the access_token result in *null*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ADAL/MSAL to get the access token in `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event of OpenID Connect OWIN middleware . And ensure you have set the response type of OpenIdConnect Options to "code id_token" to implement Hybrid flow . With ADAL library ,  specify the resource(PowerBi rest endpoint in your scenario) in `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` function .

Please refer to article :[ASP.NET Core 2.0 Azure AD Authentication](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication) .@juunas provides the explanation and code sample in this article .

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to link to the same article :) For some reason, the _OnAuthorizationCodeReceived_ event never seemed to fire using the code I started with. After referencing https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth I was able to get it working. Thanks again for the help!